# Play Framework/Activator UI index.scala.html page will not show changes that is modified in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework

I have updated my index.scala.html page in Eclipse.  The code is correct in Eclipse as well as what I can see in the Code section of Activator.

However, it will not render correctly through a browser.

I have performed the following:

1. Refreshed the project in Eclipse
2. Recompiled the project in Activator
3. Closed down and re-opened both Eclipse and Activator

Is there something I am missing?  Is there a cache in Play or Activator or Eclipse I need to clear out?

I am using Eclipse Neon 4.6.0 and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected this issue by using the command line interface...

1. Changed directory to the project folder
2. Typed in "activator"
3. When command line "$" appeared, typed in "clean"
4. To be sure, I then typed in "clean-files"

Everything looks good now...

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to clean project everytime .  One good feature of play is Hit refresh WorkFlow ..